# Web output from Kivy

Tags: python, web, kivy, kivymd

For several days now, this question has been on my mind: can I get web output with Kivy?
Something like a flutter
If you have a similar example, Haley, thank you for sending it

Comment: No.  I assume this kind of thing must be under discussion somewhere, but there's a lot of plumbing required to make that work.

Comment: What does Haley have to do with this?  What was sent?